# Taking 2D vector out of 3D Vector and replace with other 2D-Vector

Tags: c++

I want to save for an game my 2D-Vector `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> _map` in an 3D-Vector `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>> _save` with:

```
_save.push_back(_map);
```

Later I want (if condition) replace my 2D-Vector by the last-saved 2D-Vector in my 3D-Vector and then delete the last-saved 2D-Vector. My code is:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> map2;
int var = _save.size() -1; // tried with _save.back() too
map2.push_back(_save[var]);
_save.pop_back();
_map.swap(map2);
```

What am I doing wrong? What should it look like? Thank you for your help.

Following error:

```
Structure.cpp: In member function ‘void Structure::undo(bool)’:
Structure.cpp:69:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >::push_back(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > > > >::value_type&)’
     map2.push_back(_save[var]);
                              ^
Structure.cpp:69:30: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/vector:64:0,
                 from Structure.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:913:7: note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >]
       push_back(const value_type& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:913:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > > > >::value_type {aka std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >}’ to ‘const value_type& {aka const std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&}’
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:931:7: note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >]
       push_back(value_type&& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:931:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > > > >::value_type {aka std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >}’ to ‘std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >::value_type&& {aka    std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&&}’
Makefile:28: recipe for target 'Structure.o' failed
make: *** [Structure.o] Error 1
```

Comment: `map2.push_back(_save[var]);` will access one past the last element in `_save` (`_save[var]`) which generates an error.

Comment: I made a mistake, it's int var = save.size() -1, but its still not working. but thank you anyway

Comment: Please update your question with what you're actually doing then.  Also include where you put data into `_save`.

Comment: `map2.push_back(_save[var]);` should be `map2 = _save[var];`  (not going to perform well though)

Comment: It looks like `_save[var]` is a `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` and you are calling `push_back` on a `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>`. `map2` would need to be a `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>>` for that to work since you need to provide a single value for `push_back`.

Comment: That is typically what happens when you write such monster structures. Use custom classes or at least typedefs to make this readable to yourself and your team members.